# Angular Get Element Client Height when Server Side Rendering

Tags: angular, dom, serverside-javascript

This code is working fine on client side rendering. But when i use it on server side it is not working. Can someone help me how can i get clientheight and offset positions on server side.

```
 @ViewChildren('myEle') myEle: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit(){
this.myEle.changes.subscribe(item => {
      if (this.myEle.length) {
          this.offsetTop = item.first.nativeElement.offsetTop;
          this.offsetHeight = item.first.nativeElement.clientHeight
          this.changeRef.detectChanges();
      }
    })
}
```